# Why do some trigonometric functions need to be worked out to a higher degree than others using power series?

Tags: trigonometry, power-series, angle

Using power series for $\sin{x}$ why do for some values of $x$ it needs to be worked out more than others?
$$\sin{x}=x-\frac{x^{3}}{3!}+\frac{x^{5}}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+...$$
From this lets say for the value of $\sin 1$ radian , it takes only 2 terms to get an approximate enough answer of $0.8333..$
But for $\sin 5$ radians it takes 7 terms to get an approximate answer.
Why is it so? Till which terms would be plausible to use in my exams if I really needed to calculate sin values(they don't allow calculators)

Comment: Related: [1338411](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1338411/why-doesnt-using-the-approximation-sin-x-approx-x-near-0-work-for-computin) and [105593](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105593/limitations-of-approximating-sinx-x)

Comment: I will look into it , thank you !

Comment: No calculator-banning exam will ask you for $\sin5$.

Comment: Intuitively, the **convergent** sequence will not *start to converge* until the terms in the sequence are very close to $0$.  Consider the sequence of terms $$\frac{5^1}{1!}, ~\frac{5^3}{3!}, ~\frac{5^5}{5!},  ~\frac{5^7}{7!}, ~\frac{5^9}{9!}.$$  The first few terms are not very close to $0$.

Comment: ah that makes sense intuitively @user2661923 for me so for values close to 0 the first few terms are plausible and higher the value higher number of terms are needed to get an approx

Comment: As others noted, smaller argument will lead to quicker convergence. So use redaction formulas! $\sin 5=\sin(5-2\pi) \approx -\sin 1.28$

Comment: Thats a good idea too ! @Vasili thank you